# What is the visual indication code on the Stack Overflow main page?

Tags: support

Where can I find an explanation to the visual indicator the Stack Overflow main page is using?

Obviously the number of votes (up), views and answer is straightforward, but what is the meaning of the green box around the answers? And what is the green font color meaning (for answers count)?

Comment: See [What do the colors on Stack Overflow mean?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22184/what-do-the-colors-on-stack-overflow-mean)

Comment: @Bart: thanks - i was looking for this FAQ page for a long time... don't know how i missed it